# Emacs custom syntactic analysis

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, the syntactic analysis is surprisingly little.

For example, if I wish to indent parameter names differently than the types in a function declaration, like so:

```
void myfunction(
    int
        test
);
```

`int` is considered an `arglist-intro`, and `test` is considered as `arglist-cont`. However, if I add any more parameters, they'll all be considered `arglist-cont`, so indenting `arglist-cont` wouldn't do the desired effect.

So here's what I'm wondering: Is it possible to make my own syntactic analysis thingy for emacs so that it'll recognize and differentiate cases like this (this isn't the only case, by the way)? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can write whatever you want. Emacs is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), it comes with sources, so you can modify them as you wish.

However, please be aware that Emacs is quite widely used, including by some very smart [hackers](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html). This means that Emacs limitations *usually* (but, of course, not always!) have a good reason behind them (in your case, the reason is that the C syntax is quite complex). The implication is that doing what you want to do might be harder than you might be thinking. Not that it should discourage you, of course!

PS. You asked "*is it possible* to make my own syntactic analysis", not "*how* to do that" :-)

PPS. As for "*how*", you will have to start with [`cc-engine.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/cc-engine.el).

Comment: I see, yes, I had a feeling it would theoretically be possible ... and good point, I updated my answer ("And if so, how?") =p

Comment: Start with `progmodes/cc-engine.el` (see PPS). I know you would prefer a ready patch, but, I am afraid, I have no time for that. :-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm checking it out right now ... looks like I have a bit of work cut out for me haha